# Kentico - Captcha validation in newsletter subscription working against bots?

Tags: bots, captcha, kentico, newsletter

I have a newsletter subscription form on a website using Kentico 9. There is a simple captcha : "prompts users to retype a sequence of numbers from an image". Since a few month, I have noticed a lot of new subscriptions with email address that can look real because of the domain. But names attached to the email address are only a series of letters (example : vPkGNFtUjyxcEQ). I verified some email address on CleanTalk and they were reported as spam.

Is it possible for bots to subscribe to the newsletter even with this kind of captcha? How can I prevent that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for bots to submit those old captcha forms.  You're better off to introduce the [reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html) v2 or v3 on your site.  There is some code on the [old Kentico Marketplace](https://devnet.kentico.com/old-marketplace/inline-controls/new-recaptcha) which allows you to import and use the new reCaptcha functionality.